# how can i have a text field which have text in it and when the user clicks on the text field the text inside the field vanishes

Tags: python, html, django, aptana

i want to add a text inside a text-field which vanishes when user clicks on the text-field.
How can i do it?
I am using django-form

form.py

```
class CategoriesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Categories
```

model.py

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    category_name=models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.category_name
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think it's called "placeholder"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `attrs` parameter for form field widget like this:

```
from django.forms import TextInput


class CategoriesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Categories
        widgets = {
            'category_name': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE'})
        }
```

[Here is documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

Comment: Note on IE, this is only supported on version 10+: see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Comment: I think IE8 must die)) But if you want to support old browsers you can use something like this https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

In your forms.py you can write like this then it will show blur text in text box

```
first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('First Name'),max_length=30, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Please Enter Your First Name'}))
```